# How to terminate openRTSP on Windows cleanly and/or send a signal in windows

Tags: windows, signals, rtsp-client

According to the [openRTSP page](http://www.live555.com/openRTSP/#quicktime) you must "terminate it cleanly, by signalling it with SIGHUP or SIGUSR1". Those don't exist in Windows so is there a method already coded openRTSP for windows I can instigate, or is there a way to signal in windows?

Comment: The cue is "open".  The source code is the documentation.

Comment: If you don't know then please don't comment; if you do know then please add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers I have found are:

- No, you cannot signal in Windows.
- No, there is no alternative way coded in openRTSP. The windows build simply #ifdefs out the signalling code.

A named Mutex is probably the easiest way of coding up the same feature.